# Tkinter window not updating after changing the window.columnconfigure()

Tags: python, tkinter

I just started using python and I am trying to make a simple gui that consists of 3 frames. One on the left, one on the right and one in the middle. Later I'd like to add buttons and stuff to those frames but for now that is all. I want the left frame to disappear or appear again if I press the escape key. To do this I have written the following code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, Frame

class Main:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.init_gui()

    def init_gui(self):
        self.root.title("Gui Testing")
        self.root.minsize(900,600)

        self.root.bind("<Escape>", self.toggle_left_menu)

        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=200)
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(2, minsize=250)
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # main 3 panels
        self.left_menu_active = True
        self.left_menu = Frame(self.root, bg="#333")
        self.left_menu.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.center = Frame(self.root, bg="white")
        self.center.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

        self.right_menu = Frame(self.root, bg="#888")
        self.right_menu.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        
        self.toggle_left_menu()

    def toggle_left_menu(self, event=None):
        if self.left_menu_active == True:
            self.left_menu_active = False
            
            self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=0)
            self.left_menu.grid_forget()
        else:
            self.left_menu_active = True

            self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=200)
            self.left_menu.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
        
Main().start()
```

The problem is that when I press escape, nothing happens. However, when I then move the window by clicking on it and dragging it, it updates all of a sudden and it shows the window the way I want it. So the code seems to be working but the window isn't updating for some reason.

I don't know what I can do about that. I found out that it does update the grid positions of the left and the center frame, but the `grid_configure()` doesn't seem to update without moving the window.

Is there a way to update the frame or to achieve the frame toggling in some other way?

**Edit:**

The problem has been solved by adding a button to each frame. Now the frames are not empty anymore it seems works. I also edited the `toggle_left_menu()` function a bit. This is what I changed:

Added Buttons:

```
    self.test_button1 = Button(self.left_menu, text="left", padx=10, pady=5)
    self.test_button1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    self.test_button2 = Button(self.center, text="center", padx=10, pady=5)
    self.test_button2.grid(row=0, column=0)

    self.test_button3 = Button(self.right_menu, text="right", padx=10, pady=5)
    self.test_button3.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Edited `toggle_left_menu()`:

```
def toggle_left_menu(self, event=None):
    if self.left_menu.winfo_viewable():
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=0)
        self.left_menu.grid_remove()
    else:
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=200)
        self.left_menu.grid()
```

This worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Are you running on OSX?

Comment: @BryanOakley Nope, I'm running on Windows 10

Comment: The issue will be gone if you put something in the frames.

Comment: @acw1668 It worked, thanks! Why does it not work when there is nothing in your frame though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending Bryan Oakley's example ~ you have to toggle the `minsize`, as well. As an aside, I classed out all of your gui and made `Main` the `root`. All that `self.root.this` and `self.root.that` is unnecessary this way. Also, you would have had to do this anyway, unless you intended to dump your entire gui contents into your `init_gui` method. If your app is large that would be a nightmare to keep track of. As an added bonus, I made the whole `toggle_menu` method dynamic so it can toggle either menu. You can change the key-bindings, to whatever. I used `Escape then l` for `left_menu` and `Escape then r` for `right_menu`.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, Frame


class LeftMenu(Frame):
    @property
    def minsize(self):
        return 200
        
    def __init__(self, master, row=0, column=0, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='nswe')
        
        
class RightMenu(Frame):
    @property
    def minsize(self):
        return 250
        
    def __init__(self, master, row=0, column=0, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='nswe')
       

class Center(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, row=0, column=0, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='nswe')


class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.bind("<Escape><l>", self.toggle_menu)
        self.bind("<Escape><r>", self.toggle_menu)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=200)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, minsize=250)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # main 3 panels
        self.left_menu  = LeftMenu(self, 0, 0, bg="#333")
        self.center     = Center(self, 0, 1, bg="white")
        self.right_menu = RightMenu(self, 0, 2, bg="#888")
        
        self.toggle_menu(menu=self.left_menu)

    def toggle_menu(self, event=None, menu=None):
        if event and event.char in 'lr':
            menu = self.left_menu if event.char == 'l' else self.right_menu
            
        if menu:
            if menu.winfo_viewable():
                self.grid_columnconfigure(menu.grid_info()['column'], minsize=0)
                menu.grid_remove()
            else:
                menu.grid()
                self.grid_columnconfigure(menu.grid_info()['column'], minsize=menu.minsize)
                
            self.after_idle(self.event_generate, '<Configure>')
           
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Main()
    root.title("Gui Testing")
    root.minsize(900,600)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe cause im a beginner, can you explain what `@property` is? or does?

Comment: Thanks! I was not really planning to make something big but I think it's good practice to make frames the way you do anyway. It is a lot nicer to read. Is it true that by using `class example(Frame)` you are kind of extending the Frame class? Just like you can say `class example extends Frame` in java? Oh, and what does the `if __name__ == "__main__"` do?

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ sure, it's just a `getter`. If I wanted to also make a `setter`, I would use `@minsize.setter`. Without the setter "you can't set it". I put that in quotes cause you can hack past the `getter` and set it. However just doing this  `self.left_menu.minsize = 500` will not work, without a `setter`. Basically, if you play nice `@property` is read only without a corresponding `setter`.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry I just edited my comment when you replied, I had one more question. Hope you saw it.

Comment: @TijmenGroot ~ it's the proper pep8 way to initialize a main script. By main, I mean the script that you tell python to run (ie `python myscript.py`) ~ 'myscript' would be main.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that `minsize` only affects the *minimum* size. If the left frame is visible and is more than zero pixels wide, setting the `minsize` to zero isn't going to make the frame smaller. So, one step is to remove the `minsize=200` option for column 0.

Since you are using `grid`, the best way to hide or show a frame is to use `grid_remove` to remove the widget, and then `grid` to restore it. `grid_remove` will remove the widget from the window but remember all of its settings. When you subsequently call `.grid()`, all of the previous settings will be used.

You can also just check if the window is visible or not without having to manage a boolean flag since your function is a toggle. That simplifies the code a bit.

Also, I think there's a bug on some versions of tk (the library upon which tkinter is built) that prevents the window from refreshing in this specific type of situation. What works for me is to synthetically generate a `<Configure>` event on the root window.

Rolling all of that together, this version of your toggle function works for me on OSX without any other modifications to your code.

```
def toggle_left_menu(self, event=None):
    if self.left_menu.winfo_viewable():
        self.left_menu.grid_remove()
        self.root.after_idle(self.root.event_generate, '<Configure>')
    else:
        self.left_menu.grid()
        self.root.after_idle(self.root.event_generate, '<Configure>')
```

Comment: OP might also want to add a `self.root.grid_propagate(0)` in `init_gui()` so the frames keep their sizes as the left one appears and appears.

Comment: @martineau: I disagree. There is almost never a time when `grid_propagate(0)` is appropriate. Eventually they will be putting other widgets in those frames and that will just make it more difficult to create a responsive UI.

Comment: I was already looking for a way to use `winfo_` to check if the frame was viewable or not but somehow missed that one, so thanks a lot for pointing that out! I've tried the rest of your code. It does properly update now, but the center window still doesn't fill the area of the left menu when it disappears.

Comment: @TijmenGroot: oh, I see. I wasn't noticing it because on OSX the background of the root window is white.

Comment: @TijmenGroot: I've updated my answer to generate the `<Configure>` event after the UI is idle. That makes it work on my system.

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried the edited version but it's still the same for me. Isn't it because of the `self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=200)`? The `grid_remove()` doesn't reset the minsize to 0 right? What @acw1668 said in the comments under my question worked by the way. I added 3 buttons and added one to each frame and combined it with what you said about `grid_remove()` and `winfo_viewable()` to get it to work.

Comment: @TijmenGroot: yes, I forgot to mention that I removed the minsize.